# Pandas read_csv failing on columns with null characters

Tags: python, pandas

Column y below should be ['Reg', 'Reg', 'Swp', 'Swp']

```
In [1]: pd.read_csv('/tmp/test3.csv')  
Out[1]:  
x,y  
 ^@^@^@,Reg  
 ^@^@^@,Reg  
I,Swp  
I,Swp  

In [2]: ! cat /tmp/test3.csv  
     x    y  
0  
1  NaN  NaN  
2    I  Swp  
3    I  Swp    

In [3]: f = open('/tmp/test3.csv', 'rb'); print(repr(f.read()))  
'x,y\n \x00\x00\x00,Reg\n \x00\x00\x00,Reg\nI,Swp\nI,Swp\n'
```

Comment: Please show `f = open('/tmp/test3.csv', 'rb'); print(repr(f.read()))`

Comment: Updated question to show data

Comment: posted as [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2741).

Comment: Faced the issue with null values and pandas 0.18 on Windows. After an update to 0.19.1 all works with no problems.

Comment: Actually, to correct myself. It works but not completely correct. With 0.19.1, the columns are kept right but the text in a cell with the null value gets trimmed after null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I could reproduce the problem, but don't know how to fix it with `pd.read_csv`. Here is a workaround:

```
In [46]: import numpy as np
In [47]: arr = np.genfromtxt('test3.csv', delimiter = ',', 
                             dtype = None, names = True)

In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
   x    y
0     Reg
1     Reg
2  I  Swp
3  I  Swp
```

---

Note that with `names = True` the first valid line of the csv is interpreted as column names (and therefore does not affect the dtype of the values on the subsequent lines.) Thus, if the csv file contains numerical data such as

```
In [22]: with open('/tmp/test.csv','r') as f:
   ....:     print(repr(f.read()))
   ....:     
'x,y,z\n \x00\x00\x00,Reg,1\n \x00\x00\x00,Reg,2\nI,Swp,3\nI,Swp,4\n'
```

Then genfromtxt will assign a numerical dtype to the third column (`<i4` in this case).

```
In [19]: arr = np.genfromtxt('/tmp/test.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype = None, names = True)

In [20]: arr
Out[20]: 
array([('', 'Reg', 1), ('', 'Reg', 2), ('I', 'Swp', 3), ('I', 'Swp', 4)], 
      dtype=[('x', '|S3'), ('y', '|S3'), ('z', '<i4')])
```

However, if the numerical data is intermingled with bytes such as `'\x00'` then genfromtxt will be unable to recognize this column as numerical and will therefore resort to assigning a string dtype. Nevertheless, you can force the dtype of the columns by manually assigning the `dtype` parameter. For example,

```
In [11]: arr = np.genfromtxt('/tmp/test.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype = [('x', '|i4'), ('y', '|S3')], names = True)
```

sets the first column `x` to have dtype `|i4` (4-byte integers) and the second column `y` to have dtype `|S3` (3-byte string). See [this doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) for more information on available dtypes.

Comment: @user1827356: Yes, my mistake. By neglecting to provide `names = True`, `genfromtext` was reading the first line of the csv as data, not as column names. Since the first line contained strings, the dtype was being set to strings, despite the subsequent lines containing numerical data. I've updated my answer to show how `names = True` and/or `dtype` can be used to set the columns to appropriate types.